# Piping stdout from one command into stdin for another, and then to a writable stream

Tags: node.js, stream, imagemagick, raspberry-pi, child-process

With the code in `app.js` I am able to pipe the output from the **`raspistill`** command spawned in `camera()` in `camerautil.js` to a writable stream. But instead of the writable stream, I want to pipe the output into the **`convert`** command spawned in `resize()` and then pipe stdout from ***that*** command to a writable stream.

What I have tried:

```
var streamOut = fs.createWriteStream('./image.jpg');
camerautil.camera().pipe(camerautil.resize(streamOut, 1, 1));
```

It throws the following error:

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: Cannot pipe. Not readable.
    at WriteStream.Writable.pipe (_stream_writable.js:162:22)
    at Object.exports.resize (/home/pi/dev/app/camerautil.js:27:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/dev/app/index3.js:5:37)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

This is my (working) code:

**app.js**

```
var camerautil = require('./camerautil'),
    fs = require('fs');

var streamOut = fs.createWriteStream('./image.jpg');
camerautil.camera().pipe(streamOut);
```

**camerautil.js**

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    Stream = require('stream');

exports.camera = function() {
    var child = spawn('raspistill', ['-w', 320, '-h', 240, '-n', '-t', 1, '-o', '-']);

    var stream = new Stream();

    child.stderr.on('data', stream.emit.bind(stream, 'error'));
    child.stdout.on('data', stream.emit.bind(stream, 'data'));
    child.stdout.on('end', stream.emit.bind(stream, 'end'));
    child.on('error', stream.emit.bind(stream, 'error'));

    return stream;
}

exports.resize = function(streamIn, width, height) {
    var child = spawn('convert', ['-', '-resize', width + 'x' + height, '-']);

    var stream = new Stream();

    child.stderr.on('data', stream.emit.bind(stream, 'error'));
    child.stdout.on('data', stream.emit.bind(stream, 'data'));
    child.stdout.on('end', stream.emit.bind(stream, 'end'));
    child.on('error', stream.emit.bind(stream, 'error'));

    streamIn.pipe(child.stdin);

    return stream;
}
```

I should mention that I'm running node v0.12.0 on a Raspberry Pi.  The **`raspistill`** command is for taking pictures with the camera module.  The **`convert`** command is part of ImageMagick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some fiddling, I found the solution.

```
var camerautil = require('./camerautil'),
    fs = require('fs');

var streamOut = fs.createWriteStream('./image.jpg');
camerautil.resize(camerautil.camera(), 1, 1).pipe(streamOut);
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be simpler to stream into the `gm` module (A wrapper for Imagemagick). If that will install on a Raspberry PI that is.

```
var gm = require('gm')
gm(camerautil.camera())
  .resize('100', '100')
  .stream('jpg')
  .pipe(streamOut)
```

https://github.com/aheckmann/gm#streams